# ping works, ssh goes timeout

Tags: sshd, openssh

I have ubuntu 16.04 (mate) running on my laptop(10.197.1.xx) and desktop(10.141.200.xxx). From either of these I am able to ping the other. But the ssh goes *timeout* (it doesn't refuse connection, or give any warning, or error message).

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.197.1.xxx [10.197.1.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.197.1.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.197.1.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
```

The PC and the Laptop in question both have **openssh-server** installed.

```
$ sudo service sshd status

● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-04-10 09:59:50 IST; 4h 49min ago
  Process: 3682 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
 Main PID: 1096 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─1096 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Apr 10 10:37:18 H110M-DS2 systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell serve
Apr 10 10:37:18 H110M-DS2 sshd[1096]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
Apr 10 10:37:18 H110M-DS2 systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Apr 10 10:37:18 H110M-DS2 sshd[1096]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Apr 10 10:37:18 H110M-DS2 sshd[1096]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Apr 10 10:37:18 H110M-DS2 systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell serve
Apr 10 10:37:18 H110M-DS2 sshd[1096]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
Apr 10 10:37:18 H110M-DS2 systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Apr 10 10:37:18 H110M-DS2 sshd[1096]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Apr 10 10:37:18 H110M-DS2 sshd[1096]: Server listening on :: port 22.
```

The firewall status is **inactive**

```
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

What could be wrong? How do I make the ssh work.

**UPDATE**

The `traceroute` program produced the following output

```
traceroute to 10.197.1.xxx (10.197.1.xxx), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  router.xxx.xxxx.xx.in (10.xxx.xxx.1)  1.069 ms  1.388 ms  1.691 ms
 2  10.xxx.xxx.1 (10.xxx.xxx.1)  0.820 ms  0.814 ms  0.974 ms
 3  172.xx.x.1 (172.xx.x.1)  0.371 ms  0.384 ms  0.375 ms
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Comment: 1) from either host, can you `ssh localhost` ? (this should be yes) 2) hosts looks like on different network, are there any NAT involved ?

Comment: Try to do `traceroute 10.197.1.xxx` and `traceroute --tcp -p 22 10.197.1.xxx` - these commands may help you find the intermediate router blocking ssh.

Comment: @Archemar 1) Yes     2) The PC is on a wired network, and LAPTOP is on wireless network. I believe there is a NAT somewhere. I have seen other people use ssh in my campus.

Comment: @lav updated information

Comment: Most probably the router with IP address `172.xx.x.1` blocks SSH access (by dropping packets), but passes pings. You should contact your network administrator.

Comment: Try to run `tcpdump port 22` to see if the initial TCP packets with the SYN flags can pass through.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ssh
sudo ufw allow 22
```

That's the very minimum. It allows unlimited failed password attempts on a known port. Direct root-login is disabled (you can still su and sudo once logged in). If your username and password are guessable and the Internet can see the server, somebody will eventually break in.

By Default root user is not allowed to ssh from outside in ubuntu. you can change to

```
sudo sed -ir 's/^(PermitRootLogin) .+/\1 yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

if still you are facing problem pls try `telnet machineip 22` it ll show you is 22 port accessible from other machine.
Try to make ssh secure follow this [link](https://thepcspy.com/read/making-ssh-secure/)